# How to change the star-image of Jquery star rating from fyneworks to a different image

Tags: jquery, image, rating

Im using this plugin: http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating

It includes a star.gif (which actually contains the star in three different colors) and it only references this gif within the included css-file once:

```
div.star-rating,div.star-rating a{background:url(star.gif) no-repeat 0 0px}
```

I dont want to use the star.gif anymore but instead use my own images in png Format. How can I do that?

I guess there would be three options:

1. Create my own myGif.gif and reference it in the jquery-rating CSS (which I dont want, because I want to use my .png-Images and I dont really understand gif and dont know how to create one which includes several images)
2. Change the CSS-File to it references my .png-Images (the problem here would be that the gif contains the star in three different colors, but a png only contains a single image, so the color of the star wont change anymore)
3. Maybe change the Jquery-Rating Javascript Files so that it includes my pngs automatically?

What would you recommend? And how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems pretty basic.  Just change the css file to point to your images.  It's really the only solution that makes sense.

Comment: the problem is that the gif contains the star in three colors (red, yellow, grey) but a png can only contain one image as far as I know! But being able to change the color of the image (for example on-hover) is one of the key features of Jquery star rating!

Comment: the `.gif` and the `.png` can look identical:  they're both just an image.  Open up the `.gif` file in any image editor/file viewer/picture preview and look at how it is constructed.  Then make your `.png` look the same.  The technique they are using is called "image sprites".  Some research in that area would prove beneficial.  http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Comment: Thanks, that was my problem: I didnt understand nor knew about the concept of image sprites. But I solved my problem now.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is change the background image of the DIVs and As created by the plugin, like this:

```
div.star-rating, div.star-rating a{
    background-image:url('/path/to/your/green-stars.gif');
}
```

Here is an example we made:
http://jsfiddle.net/tLuqJ/1/

And here is the original image you can use as the basis to make your own colours:
http://jquery-star-rating-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/star.gif

Answer (score -1):

Override it in your own css file:

```
 div.star-rating,div.star-rating a{
    background:url(myimg.png) no-repeat 0 0px !important;
 }
```

Comment: Maybe the !important is not even necessary

Comment: I would not recommend this, because the browser will have to load the original and the new one, even though you are only displaying the new one.  That's one extra http request.

Comment: @Stephen: the problem then becomes when they update their css file, you'll have to merge your changes every release. CSS is meant to cascade (hence the name) and overriding default behavior with a custom stylesheet is the correct answer.

Comment: Expound upon your reasoning, please.  What if one were to theoretically override ten images with a custom stylesheet.  That would result in twenty HTTP requests for ten items, basically doubling the webpage load time of those images, and costing you money in needless bandwidth fees.  Cascading trivial styles like borders and colors?  Yes.  Cascading images?  Hell no.

Comment: @Stephen: as always, there is a tradeoff between programmer time and performance. The cost of these things is of course idiosyncratic, so no general statement can be made. However, I can think of very few times where the maintenance cost of manually merging each change would be less than the bandwidth cost. (If you have 20 images, you should probably be spriting them if you're concerned about performance...)

Comment: Not using an image that the browser has loaded flies in the face of reason.

Comment: @Stephen: you wouldn't be arguing for premature optimization, would you?

Comment: @Bane you'd be surprised how slow an image heavy website gets, especially if you are loading images you don't plan to use.  Try that in mobile.

Comment: @Stephen No, I wouldn't be surprised. But I believe one of the first principles of good CS philosophy since at least the 80s has been don't prematurely optimize; always measure first.  If u didn't measure, you have no business optimizing something that could otherwise be saving dev-time.